# Can't reorder items in Text formats

Tags: input-formats

On Drupal 7.15, I cannot save reordered draggable items at /admin/config/content/formats.
That is the dialog with all text formats and their options, and dragging them in order force their order of appearace.

I am able to drag items and reorder them, but after saving, items returns in previous order, in spite Drupal says "The text format ordering has been saved."

I do not have clue yet how to troubleshoot this issue, as there is no error anywhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was very strange issue, now solved, but can't texactly the point that solved it, as i ran extensive code/config sweep both on code / server side. (Including Apache restarts, MySQL restarts, module maintance (many unused gone with the wind), APC configs, and running registry rebuids.